# Подсказка в трее с помощью NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, winforms

Существует такая задача: есть иконка приложения в трее, при показе определенного окна приложения всплывает подсказка (что-то вроде заголовка определенной новости) . Затем,щелкая мышкой на подсказке мы переходим на другую форму, в которой уже видим полное содержание новости.
Я использовал стандартный контрол `NotifyIcon`.
В принципе реализовать это несложно, но вот по-моему функционала этому контролу не хватает. Есть несколько непонятных следующих моментов:

1. Почему при вызове подсказки, как только я начинаю двигать мышкой подсказка скрывается? Просто в методе `ShowBalloonTip` первый аргумент - это как раз активное время подсказки и я предполагал, что подсказка должна быть активна заданное время, пока её не закроют.
2. Можно ли как-то реализовать вызов подсказки на бесконечное время, до тех пор пока её не закрыли?
3. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора на подсказку менялся тип курсора и, к примеру, текст подсказки становился подчеркнутым или какого другого цвета. Просто во многих стандартных контролах это легко указывается через свойство Cursor и всё, но здесь такого свойства нет.
4. И еще один вопрос про настройку внешнего вида подсказки: опять же не нашел, где можно отключить иконку гаечного ключа, та что рядом со значком закрытия сообщения (при её нажатии мы попадаем в меню настройки значков и уведомлений отображаемых на панели задач, а мне это не надо).

Заранее спасибо.

Если бы кто-нибудь дал ссылку на какой-нибудь другой класс с более богатым функционалом, был бы также крайне признателен.

Comment: Насколько я помню, у NotifyIcon очень скудный функционал, да и работает не во всех версиях Windows. Проще написать для этих целей свое окно со свойством FormBorderStyle.None и позиционированием в нижнем правом углу.

Comment: Соглашусь с Ilya Pirogov - так и есть, **NotifyIcon** обладает достаточно скудным функционалом,и все компании, что я знаю, сами "пишут" сей функционал. Поищу в своей бибилиотеке подобное, если найду-кину,а то сейчас на работе)

Comment: [The rule for taskbar notifications is that they are there to, well, *notify* the user of something.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx)

Comment: Неплохой класс вроде :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3285/TaskbarNotifier-a-skinnable-MSN-Messenger-like-pop